# Who is the boy that gives Mace Windu water in The Clone Wars (2003)?

Tags: star-wars, clone-wars-2003

In an epic fight where Windu destroys an entire army and some sort of weird forge hammer vehicle weapon, a boy is standing on top of a hill and watching everything. After the fight, Windu meets the boy on top of the hill and gets offered water. Who is this boy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### His name is [Paxi Sylo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Paxi_Sylo).

From the [archived version of his page at the Star Wars databank](http://web.archive.org/web/20110629023915/http://www.starwars.com/databank/character/paxisylo/index.html):

> For ten generations, the Sylo family maintained a large farm in the outback of Dantooine. Griggen and Tashna Sylo worked hard to harvest tritacale and yot beans, supplying a larder to feed their family of seven children, as well as to sell offworld.
>   The youngest child, Paxi, was the daydreamer of the family. The quiet soft-spoken child would sketch quietly on his datapad or on spare flimisplast, doodling tales of heroic adventure on distant worlds. He had heard fragments of stories of the Jedi Knights, and how they were engaged in an epic conflict called the Clone Wars, but Dantooine was so far off the beaten path that such stories might as well have been fiction.
>
> This all changed one fateful day when Paxi was nine years old. The Confederacy sought to gain a foothold on Dantooine, to further the protection of nearby Muunilinst. The Jedi responded by sending one of their greatest warriors, Mace Windu, with a clone army to repel the Confederacy.
>
> Paxi watched with awe as Windu and his troops defeated the Separatists. He was spellbound, and for the next few weeks, his doodle-datapad was filled with crude illustrations of Mace Windu single-handedly destroying a seismic tank. It was all the young boy could talk about.

You can see a picture of him on [this archived news page](http://web.archive.org/web/20040403194004/http://www.starwars.com/hyperspace/about/news/news20040326.html):

[image: paxi]